# how can i define a default post thumbnail for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails, default

my functions file

`<?php
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 
add_image_size( 'custom-size', 600, 110 );`

like this
index file a mean loop

```
<div class="konu-resim"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><img src="<?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() )
    the_post_thumbnail();
else
    echo '<img src="' . trailingslashit( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ) . 'images/deneme.jpg' . '" alt="" />';
```

?>

i try this one but doesnt work

i want default thumbnail with post url

Comment: You mean you want a specific image to be in place, rather than a featured image, until a featured image is called?

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

1) add following code in your functions.php file

```
<?php

 add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'my_post_thumbnail_html' );

  function my_post_thumbnail_html( $html ) {

    if ( empty( $html ) )
            $html = '<img src="' . trailingslashit( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ) . 'images/default-thumbnail.jpg' . '" alt="" />';

            return $html;
        }
?>
```

2) display like (if future image not set in back end then it'll display default image )

```
<?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() )
        the_post_thumbnail();
    else
        echo '<img src="' . trailingslashit( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ) . 'images/default-thumbnail.jpg' . '" alt="" />';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ){
    the_post_thumbnail();
    } else { 
    echo '<img src="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/images/deneme.jpg" alt="" />'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this please

```
<?php
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 
    add_image_size( 'custom-size', 600, 110 );` 

    like this
    index file a mean loop

    <div class="konu-resim"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {

    the_post_thumbnail();
    } else { ?>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>images/deneme.jpg" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /></a></div>
```

To Reffer :[enter link description here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-set-a-default-fallback-image-for-wordpress-post-thumbnails/)